# Woocommerce Register Error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

Before posting this question i have tried solution posted here https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/202828575-Redirect-to-a-custom-page-after-logging-in

I need to redirect user at specific product page after registration.

Login redirect shown in above site has worked for me.

But register redirect is not working.

I am using twentysixteen theme with woocommerce.

Any help???

Below code worked like charm. Suggested by ....

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wcs_login_redirect');
function wcs_login_redirect( $redirect ) {    
 $redirect = '/product/pay-to-book';
 return $redirect;
}

add_action( 'register_form', 'hiddern_redirect_url' );
function hiddern_redirect_url() {
?>
<input type="hidden" name="redir_post_register" value="<?php echo '/product/pay-to-book'; ?>" />
<?php   
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'redirect_post_registration');
function redirect_post_registration( $redirect ) {

if ( $_POST['redir_post_register'] ) {
    $redirect = $_POST['redir_post_register'];
}
return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a hidden field to registration form which can hold the URL where you want to redirect the user post registration. Below code will help you for that:

```
<?php
add_action( 'register_form', 'hiddern_redirect_url' );
function hiddern_redirect_url() {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="redir_post_register" value="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>" />
<?php   
}
?>
```

Then, using `woocommerce_registration_redirect` hook you can alter the default redirection URL to what you just set above. Please see code below:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'redirect_post_registration');
function redirect_post_registration( $redirect ) {

    if ( $_POST['redir_post_register'] ) {
        $redirect = $_POST['redir_post_register'];
    }

    return $redirect;
}
```

You need to add both above code snippets to your theme's functions.php file. Also you need to change `<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>` in first code snippet to product URL which you want.

Comment: thanks for reply. However it did not work. check code in answer below

Comment: Please let me know which code you want me to check? Also, please provide more details on what happened after placing this code in functions.php file.

Comment: i am not able to post code the way you are posting. can you please tell me how to?

Comment: Please see this for help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: please check code in my updated question.

Comment: it is working now. Thanks for the help. Actually programmer is out on vacation so i had to do this. I am an SEO and only know basic php. You helped me, let me know if you need any help in SEO ;-)

Comment: Good to know that I could help. Please accept the answer by upvoting it and clicking on tick mark.